# Calculated field shows text instead of image

Tags: calculated-column, image

SP Online, task list. Created calculated field with this formula:

```
=IF([Task Status]="Completed","<DIV><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png /></DIV>","")
```

[image]

it works but does not show icon (shows text):
[image]

Returned value is 'Number', so as I uunderstang SharePoint should render html and show image.. How can I fix it?

### Update:

Thank You much guys for Your answers! Replaced with CSR (attached like "~sitecollection/libname/filename.js" in Webpart -> Miscellaneous -> JsLink section):

```
(function () {
    // custom JSlink overrides hierarchytaskslist.js, so we need to load it by ourself
    // https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211494/csr-to-render-task-status-destroys-task-checkboxes
    RegisterSod('hierarchytaskslist.js', '/_layouts/15/hierarchytaskslist.js');
    LoadSodByKey('hierarchytaskslist.js', null);

    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Fields = {
        'Ico':
        {
            'View': returnIcon
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();


function returnIcon(ctx) {

    var isCurrentItemCompleted = ctx.CurrentItem["Checkmark"];
    console.log("Is current item completed: " + isCurrentItemCompleted);

    if (isCurrentItemCompleted === "Yes") {

        var pathToIcon = "<span><img src='" + "https://server.sharepoint.com" + "/Style%20Library/project/ok-24.png' width='24px' height='24px'style='border:0px;'></span>";

        return pathToIcon;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The only problem that remains - is that all works like a charm on Views pages, but not on Home.aspx, where I have other webparts with custom javascript.. Select/Deselect tasks does not wotk there at all, maybe something breaks hierarchytaskslist.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality using Client Side Rendering. Below code show how to compare 2 columns and show image icon in the 3rd column based on the condition.

```
(function () {
var overrideCurrentContext = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};
overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Fields = {
    'Target_x0020_Status': { 'View': TargetStatus }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);
})();


function TargetStatus(ctx) {

var totalSalesVal =ctx.CurrentItem.Total_x0020_Sales.replace(",", "");
var targetSalesVal =ctx.CurrentItem.Sales_x0020_Target.replace(",", "");

if(parseInt(totalSalesVal) > parseInt(targetSalesVal))
{
 returnvalue = "<span><img src='/sites/Playground/SiteAssets/TargetMet.jpg' width='20px' height='20px'style='border:0px;'></span>";
 return returnvalue ;

}
else if(parseInt(targetSalesVal)- parseInt(totalSalesVal) <=1000 )
{
 returnvalue = "<span><img src='/sites/Playground/SiteAssets/Reaching.jpg' width='20px' height='20px'style='border:0px;'></span>";
 return returnvalue ;
}
else
{
 returnvalue = "<span><img src='/sites/Playground/SiteAssets/LongWay.jpg' width='20px' height='20px'style='border:0px;'></span>";
 return returnvalue ;
}
}
```

[image]

You can view more detailed information in my article [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-kpi-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-2016-list-view-using-client-side-rend/)

Comment: Another example has Tobias Zimmergren: https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: This is exatly the same answer as [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/259560#259560). Either the questions are equal and they should be merged, or the questions are different calling for a different answer.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint doesn't support HTML in calculated field since June 2017. So it's not working.

You can use CSR using JSLINK for achieve your functionality.

Please check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields) link for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This unofficial feature has recently been removed.

See [Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields) for more details.

Danny Engelman has provided some code to a similar question which restores this functionality. You can find it [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f).